# Android: How to make a button list with text info from database

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

I'm doing a simple "quest" app. Each quest consist of a checklist of things to do. I want to show the list of quests available with buttons showing the title of each quest.

I have each quest and its specs in a db. Following some tutorials like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) they use an ArrayAdapter to show the list, but it requires a "textview resource id" in the layout. I don't know how to pass the title of each quest (which I retrieve from the db) to the layout and put it on the button, since I never use text views.

For clarity, here is the code of the activity where I retrieve the data from de DB.

```
public class InProgress extends ListActivity {

    private questspecdao datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new questspecdao(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<questspec> values = datasource.getAllQuests();

        ArrayAdapter<questspec> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<questspec>(this,
                R.layout.questrow, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us where you got stuck. A piece of your code might help a little.

Comment: I've put the code of the activity, but like I said earlier, that `ArrayAdapter` wont work because i'm not using text views in the `R.layout.questrow` layout. I'm using buttons.

Comment: @Nocturn, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making the wrong adaptation of the ArrayAdapter.

According with Android's official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), an ArrayAdapter, *"By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView"*

That means it only supports a TextView so you have to implement it like:

```
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array /** Your data String[] goes here. */);

    /** Sets adapter to your declared ListView. */
    youtListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

If you want a customized list item then you must create your own adapter:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            /** Inflate a xml layout to the View. */
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

            /**Declare all of your items at the previous defined rowlayout xml file . */
        TextView textView = (TextView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView .findViewById(R.id.icon);

            /** Set some values to the declared item views. */
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        if (values[position].contains("XXXXXXX")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.y);
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helped you :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to customize my own array adapter. Let me check on that and see if it works!